# How to cancel a pending signal?

Tags: linux, signals

How can I cancel a sent signal to a process which is still not delivered?

Consider the scenario where I have sent a signal to a process, but the process was in un-interruptible state.

I am doing a conditional wait for the signal to be handled. But since it did not I want to continue executing further. In that case, is there a way that I can cancel the sent signal(it is not yet delivered)

Comment: Would it not be possible to use the timeout function as a work around?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Once a signal is sent, it will be sent asynchronously. It will be only be ignored if the target process is terminated or discards the signal. Just do a check in the target process to check if the signal is still necessary.

Comment: @LieRyan The scenario is typically when collecting bt of all the threads. So, its actually a quite generic code. Would not be possible to handle it for all the threads.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libbacktrace/BacktraceCurrent.cpp#142

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A pending signal is canceled if that signal is ignored before the signal is delivered. You just have to ignore the signal. You can do this with `sigaction()` by setting the `sa_handler` field in `struct sigaction` to `SIG_IGN`.

Here's some example code that illustrates this and shows that it works. The code does the following:

1. Blocks `SIGINT` so that we have a window of time to send it `SIGINT` when it is blocked - this will generate a pending `SIGINT` that will be delivered when the process signal mask is changed to a mask that does not include `SIGINT` (and will be canceled if the signal is ignored).
2. Waits for you to send `SIGINT`
3. Ignores `SIGINT` after knowing that a `SIGINT` is pending. This has the effect of canceling the pending signal.
4. Restores the original default action for `SIGINT`, which is to terminate the process
5. Restores the original process signal mask, that does not block `SIGINT`.
6. Waits for you to enter any character to terminate.

You can see that the process does not terminate after step 5 and waits for your input, which means that the pending signal was canceled.

Here's the code that illustrates this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    sigset_t block_sigint, prev_mask;
    sigemptyset(&block_sigint);
    sigaddset(&block_sigint, SIGINT);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &block_sigint, &prev_mask) < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't block SIGINT");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("SIGINT blocked: kill -SIGINT %ld to generate a pending SIGINT. Press return when done.\n", (long) getpid());

    /* Now, open a new terminal and send SIGINT to this process.
     *
     * After doing that, the signal will be pending delivery because it is currently blocked.
     *
     * Now, if we ignore SIGINT, the pending signal will be cancelled
     */

    getchar();

    struct sigaction ign_sigint, prev;
    ign_sigint.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    ign_sigint.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&ign_sigint.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &ign_sigint, &prev) < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't ignore SIGINT");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("SIGINT ignored - pending SIGINT was canceled.\n");

    /* Now, restore the default action for SIGINT */
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &prev, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't restore default SIGINT behavior");
        return 0;
    }

    /* And also restore the process's original sigmask, which does not block SIGINT */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev_mask, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't restore original process sigmask");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Process sigmask and action for SIGINT are now restored\n");

    /* We will not receive SIGINT at this point because it was canceled
     * So the process will block on getchar() here instead of terminating
     */
    getchar();

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I think OP might be asking how to cancel a pending signal sent to *another* process. Not how a program can cancel a pending signal it's about to receive itself.